# Need sql query to get expected output for the below,

Tags: sql, oracle

Tried the below query, but it works only for the first and second records.

```sql
Select 
  name, 
  dept, 
  sal, 
  (
    coalesce(sal, 0) + coalesce(saltodrop)
  ) as running total (
    SELECT 
      name, 
      dept, 
      sal, 
      LAG(Sal, 1, 0) OVER(
        PARTITION BY [dept] 
        ORDER BY 
          [name], 
          [dept] ASC
      ) AS [saltodrop] 
    FROM 
      dataset
  ) as data_set_extract
```

Input

```
Name dept sal
John sales 10000
Tom sales 8000
Tim sales 5000
George finance 6000
Dane finance 4000
Mike hr 5000
Meme hr 6000
Ark it 5000
```

Output

```
Name dept sal
John sales 1000
Tom sales 18000
Tim sales 23000
George finance 29000
Dane finance 33000
Mike hr 38000
Meme hr 44000
Ark it 49000
```

> Using the Oracle database, I need to add a consecutive row of the
> first two records, later the sum of the first record and second record
> with that of the third record and so on.

Comment: Describe what's going on here. Why are some sal values increased and others decreased?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Using oracle database, need to add consecutive row of first two records later the sum of first record and second record with that of third record and so on

Comment: Tried below query, but its works only for first and second record                              
   Select name,dept,sal,(coalesce(sal,0) + coalesce(saltodrop)) as running total 
(SELECT name, 
       dept, 
       sal, 
       LAG(Sal, 1, 0) OVER(PARTITION BY [dept]
       ORDER BY [name], 
                [dept] ASC) AS [saltodrop]
FROM dataset) as data_set_extract

Comment: Does that mean John should still have 10000?

Comment: Hey, edit your question and add your query attempt there instead of as a comment.

Comment: That query should not work at all as `[]` brackets around identifiers are not valid syntax in Oracle. Are you sure you are using an Oracle database?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already ordered the results then use the `SUM` analytic function and order by `ROWNUM` to keep the current ordering:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(sal) OVER (ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS cumulative_sal
FROM   table_name t;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Name, dept, sal) AS
SELECT 'John',   'sales',   10000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tom',    'sales',    8000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tim',    'sales',    5000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'George', 'finance',  6000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dane',   'finance',  4000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mike',   'hr',       5000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Meme',   'hr',       6000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ark',    'it',       5000 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NAME | DEPT | SAL | CUMULATIVE_SAL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | John | sales | 10000 | 10000 |
> | Tom | sales | 8000 | 18000 |
> | Tim | sales | 5000 | 23000 |
> | George | finance | 6000 | 29000 |
> | Dane | finance | 4000 | 33000 |
> | Mike | hr | 5000 | 38000 |
> | Meme | hr | 6000 | 44000 |
> | Ark | it | 5000 | 49000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=97a11e1631d5df08e56dd11713fdc74f)*